# Relative parent directory path for .gitignore

Tags: git

In my sbt-project I have some files that I do not want to share with my colleagues as they are personal notes and stuff like that. I want to have them `.gitignore`d. How can I do this. I placed a folder `personal` into the project and added a .gitignore there with the line

```
 ../personal/
```

I hoped that would hide the folder personal (including the responsible .gitignore) from git, but it seems this is not valid for git. How can I achieve this?

Also
    /personal/
does not work as hoped.

Answer (score 11):

## Option 1: Using a .gitgnore file

In your `personal` directory create a `.gitignore` file with the following content:

```
*
```

- Git will then ignore the `personal` directory and any files inside it.
- Ignoring files or directories outside of the `personal` directory is not possible using this approach (at least I don't know how to achieve this using this option).

## Option 2: Using the .git/info/exclude file

Add the following lines to the `.git/info/exclude` file:

```
/personal
*.dictionary
```

- Git will then ignore the `personal` directory and any files inside it.
- It will also ignore all files with a `.dictionary` suffix no matter if they are inside or outside the `personal` directory.

## Further notes & documentation

- Files already tracked by Git are not affected. The purpose of gitignore files is to ensure that certain files not tracked by Git remain untracked. To stop tracking a file that is currently tracked, use `git rm --cached`.
- [gitignore man page](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore): See section "Description" to get an overview about the different options which exist to ignore files within a git repository and when to use which option.

Comment: This is an improvement of my situation, thanks. However, it does only hide everything *in* my personal folder, but not my personal folder itself. Also, I would like to ignore thing from that .gitignore that are *outside* of my personal folder. E.g. I would like to say that all .dictionary files (inside and outside the personal folder) should be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

add a .gitignore file on your project's root directory like below

```
sbt-project
 |_ app
 |_ personal
 |_ .gitignore
```

The paths you add on `.gitignore` to be skipped should be relative to the directory where `.gitignore` file is located. In this case, add this line to skip all contents of your `personal` directory inside sbt-project

```
personal/
```